# ORS-Tool: Distances of route combination with matching attribute

Tags: qgis

I have two tables. The first table contains names and a corresponding start address (for example 6 names and 6 addresses). The second table contains the same names but with several destination addresses per name (for example 6 names and 24 addresses). I would like to find out the distance each name travels from its start address to its respective destination addresses.

I use the ORS tool. With the function "Matrix" I get every route combination, but I only want to get the route combinations where the corresponding name matches.

So to break down the example above, I want to get a total of 24 distances. Does anyone have a solution?